# how to unset/kill static int variables in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, static, int, reset

I am using static int variables  but having some problem. Problem is that its not getting reset.
If I leave this page and come again then I found previous values while I have reset it.

Please give me solution.

here is my code

```
- (void)updateQuestion:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
    static int questionCounter = 1;

    questionCounter += 1;


    count=(questionCounter%QUESTION_TIME_LIMIT);

    tfLeftTime.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",QUESTION_TIME_LIMIT];


    tmLeftTime=[[NSTimer alloc] init];
    tmLeftTime=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateLeftTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [self playMusic];
    if (questionCounter>QUESTION_PER_LEVEL) {
        if ([tmQuestion isValid]) {
            [tmQuestion invalidate];
            questionCounter=1;
            count=1;
            tmQuestion=nil;
            [self showAdvertisement];
        }
    }

}
```

Thank & Regards
Shivam

Comment: How do you use those static variables? Can you provide some code?

Comment: I have added my code in the post

Comment: Here this " count=(questionCounter%QUESTION_TIME_LIMIT);" count variable is also static Int that is declared in another functtion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use a instance variable to have the effect you want.

The counter will remain as long as the object lives, and is destroyed when you no longer need it.

Comment: Okay you mean I should declare a variable in .h file?

Comment: yes, in the interface declaration :
    @ interface myClass : NSObject
    {
        int questionCounter;
    }
    @ end

Comment: How should I accept your answer. Please guide me. Actually I dont know about it.

Comment: To the left of my answer, there is a half-transparent V, just click on it and it become green :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3401/discussion-between-geoffroy-and-shivam-s-kara)

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot declare a static variable in one method and use in in another one. I assume you declared it in the file, outside of any methods. Use instance variables instead.
2. You have a memory leak at:

   tmLeftTime=[[NSTimer alloc] init];

   tmLeftTime=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateLeftTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

First allocation of the tmLeftTime is never released.

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: target: selector: userInfo: repeats:] gives you an autoreleased timer.

Comment: Okay then how to auto release this timer

Comment: The scheduled timer is already autoreleased. When you do not need it any more call [tmLeftTime invalidate], which will stop it and remove from the runloop. Autorelease pool will take care of it later. Do not forget to nullify the pointer tmLeftTime = nil, because after is has been released you risk to have a dangling pointer.